# How to add every other letter with a random letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I'm trying to add every two letter a random letter to a string using a class and function

```
class Encryption():

    def __init__(self,seed):

        # Set a random seed and a self.seed attribute
        self.seed = seed

        # Create an empty string attribute to hold the encrypted phrase
        self.encrypted_phrase = ''

        # Use the string and random libraries to create two attributes
        # One is the correct alphabet, another is a shuffled alphabet:

        self.correct_alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
        self.shuffeled_alphabet = random.sample(correct_alphabet, seed)

    def encryption(self,message):

        appended_message = list(message)       
        for let in list(range(0, len(message), 2)):
            if let in self.correct_alphabet:
                appended_message.append(self.shuffeled_alphabet)
        return appended_message
```

So if i do

```
e2 = Encryption(3)
e2.encryption(hello)
```

it fails with the following message

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-505d8a880fb2> in <module>
----> 1 e2.encryption(message=hello)

NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using an undefined name, as the error tells you. Did you mean `message="hello"`?

Comment: I think the correct line of code is `e2.encryption("hello")`. Will post this as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is calling your code with a variable instead of a string. See comment or the other post.

---

You can also simplify and speedup as well as fix your logic using dicts - you create one dict to encode, and the reverse dict to decode. You translate each character through the dicts and ''.join afterwards using a ternary and modulo to only change every `every` letter:

```
import random
import string

class Encryption(): 
    def __init__(self,seed):
        # Set a random seed and a self.seed attribute
        random.seed(seed)
        source=string.ascii_lowercase
        crypt = random.sample(source,k=len(source))

        # one dict to encrypt
        self.enc = {k:v for k,v in zip(source,crypt)}

        # reverse crypt to decrypt 
        self.dec = {k:v for v,k in self.enc.items()}

    def encryption(self,message,every=1):
        return self.do_it(self.enc,message,every) 

    def decryption(self,message,every=1):
        return self.do_it(self.dec,message,every)  

    def do_it(self, mapper, message, every):
        # replace unknown characters (after lowercasing) by ?
        return ''.join( (mapper.get(c,"?") if i % every == 0 else c 
                         for i,c in enumerate(message.lower())))
```

Test:

```
crypto_1 = Encryption(42)
crypto_2 = Encryption(42)
crypto_3 = Encryption(99)

word = "apple1234juice"
code = crypto_1.encryption(word,2)
print(word,code,crypto_1.decryption(code,2),"Same crypto")
print(code,crypto_2.decryption(code,2),"Different crypto, same seed")
print(code,crypto_3.decryption(code,2),"Different crypto, other seed")
```

Output(reformatted- every 2nd character is kept):

```
                    p l 1?3?j i e     # are kept as is

apple1234juice     upllh1?3?jgiae     apple1?3?juice     Same crypto
upllh1?3?jgiae     apple1?3?juice                        Different crypto, same seed
upllh1?3?jgiae     gpnlf1?3?jcize                        Different crypto, other seed
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need to understand ! but I need help reading and comprehending the logic, please execuse me, I know my questions are very basic but would appreciate the help a lot ! :)
I can't understand the list comprehension in def __init__(self,seed), can you elaborate on what they exactly do ?

Comment: and what's the logic behind
def encryption(self,message,every=1):
def decryption(self,message,every=1):
def do_it(self, mapper, message, every):

Comment: @TajJu the action for encrypt and decrypt are the same - the order of the dictionarys used is different - thats why both methods call the same do_it but provide the dictionaries  the other way round. Use `"abcd"`  instead of string.ascii_lowercase and print out the dicts - with that you should be able to get what they do. maybe a piece of paper alsp helps.

Answer (score 0):

`hello` needs to be a string, as it's not a variable.

Try `e2.encryption("hello")` or something similar.

So your full code sample would be:

```
e2 = Encryption(3)
e2.encryption("hello")
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a stupid mistake from my side :P thanks !

But at the same time i was finding it difficult to achieve appending a letter from a list for every 2 letters